# Cygwin/ssh connection failing under Oracle EM 12c

Tags: ssh, oracle11g, cygwin, oracle12c

I have got Oracle Enterprise Manager 12c installed on a server (myoemhost), but when I try to add a target manually, it produces the following message :-

> Shell path is incorrect or not defined.:C:/cygwin/bin/sh.exe(SH_PATH),-c(SH_ARGS) on host mydbhost.mycompany.co.uk

I added authorised credentials of cyg_server with the correct password, and with no run/as privs (because when I did it wouldn't let me apply).

The log file produces the following results

> 2014-01-15_15-42-13:INFO:======================================Initialization START ====================================
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-13:INFO:Creating instance of ClusterBase Ops for hostnamemydbhost.mycompany.co.uk
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-13:INFO:Setting security contextSYSMAN
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-13:INFO:Setting locale succeeded in BaseDeployerOps
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-13:INFO:[action name=SSHValidations, action Description=Remote Validations, order=100, skip=false, executeAlways=false, status=null,
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-13:INFO:[action name=SSHSetup, action Description=SSH Setup, order=200, skip=false, executeAlways=false, status=null,
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-13:INFO:skipping ssh setup  since its jsch plugin
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-13:INFO: Skipping action SSHSetup based on inputs
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-13:INFO:[action name=CopyAgentImage, action Description=Transferring Agent Software to Destination Host, order=300, skip=false, executeAlways=false, status=null,
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-13:INFO: ACTIONS : SSHValidations
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-13:INFO: ACTIONS : CopyAgentImage
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-13:INFO:============Creating Deployment Vo for key : Initialization and setting status as NOT_EXECUTED
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-13:INFO:=====Creating Action Vo for actionSSHValidations
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-13:INFO:=====Creating Action Vo for actionCopyAgentImage
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-13:INFO:deploymentVo has now status: NOT_EXECUTED
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-14:INFO:Retry Count 5 sleep interval 250
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-14:INFO:==SUDO EXISTS false SUDO PRIV false
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-14:INFO:====CALLING ACTIONdoSSHValidations
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-14:INFO:updating status IN_PROGRESS for action name SSHValidations with key: SSHValidations
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-14:INFO:action:NodesAliveperform:true
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-14:INFO:===VALIDATION===:Checking for Nodes Alive
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-14:INFO:RESULT 0
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-14:INFO:====CALLING ACTIONdoNodesAlive
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-14:INFO:action:RemotePasswordCheckperform:true
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-14:INFO:===VALIDATION===:Checking Password Validity on target nodes
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-14:INFO:NODES=mydbhost.mycompany.co.uk Retry Count 5
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-14:INFO:retry count : 1
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-14:INFO:Running cmd C:/cygwin/bin/true.exe on node mydbhost.mycompany.co.uk
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-14:INFO:ssh connect timeout 60000
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-16:INFO:Exit Code : 1
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-16:INFO:Error :
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-16:INFO:Out:
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-16:INFO:Checking for password validity on target nodes : PASSED
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-16:INFO:RESULT 0
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-16:INFO:====CALLING ACTIONdoRemotePasswordCheck
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-16:INFO:action:ShPathCheckperform:true
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-16:INFO:===VALIDATION===:Checking SH_PATH on target nodes
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-16:INFO:isWrongShPath:remotePathPropertiesLoc:E:/Oracle/Middleware/oms/oui/prov/resources Platform id:233
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-16:INFO:NODES=mydbhost.mycompany.co.uk
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-16:INFO:Running cmd C:/cygwin/bin/sh.exe -c C:/cygwin/bin/true.exe on node mydbhost.mycompany.co.uk
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-16:INFO:Action description Execution of command C:/cygwin/bin/sh.exe -c C:/cygwin/bin/true.exe  on host mydbhost.mycompany.co.uk
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-16:INFO:Attempt :1 pty required false  with no inputs
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-17:INFO:C:/cygwin/bin/sh.exe -c C:/cygwin/bin/true.exe execution failed on host mydbhost.mycompany.co.uk
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-17:INFO: OUT null
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-17:INFO: ERR null
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-17:INFO: EXIT CODE1
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-17:INFO: ACTION Execution of command C:/cygwin/bin/sh.exe -c C:/cygwin/bin/true.exe  on host mydbhost.mycompany.co.uk
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-17:INFO:SH_PATH Error Message:C:/cygwin/bin/sh.exe(SH_PATH),-c(SH_ARGS) on host mydbhost.mycompany.co.uk
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-17:INFO: Jsch Validation Failed Problem :Shell Path validation failed Recommendation: Check the property values in the following files in this order, ssPaths_<plat>.properties or sPaths.properties or Paths.properties, in "E:/Oracle/Middleware/oms/oui/prov/resources" directory. If the property values are correct, then ensure the login user account is enabled for remote logins.For more details, refer to the Oracle Enterprise Manager Basic Installation Guide.
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-17:INFO:Breaking since the jsch validation  has failed
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-17:INFO:InvocationTargetException Exception
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-17:INFO:Printing Exception :java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>       at oracle.sysman.core.agentpush.ui.deployer.BaseDeployerOps.executeActions(BaseDeployerOps.java:1862)
>       at oracle.sysman.core.agentpush.ui.deployer.InitializationDeployer.deploy(InitializationDeployer.java:421)
>       at oracle.sysman.core.agentpush.ui.deployfwk.DeploymentWorker.run(DeploymentWorker.java:26)
>       at oracle.sysman.util.threadPoolManager.WorkerThread.run(Worker.java:311)
>   Caused by: oracle.sysman.core.agentpush.ui.exception.JschValidationException
>       at oracle.sysman.core.agentpush.ui.deployer.JschValidationOps.doShPathCheck(JschValidationOps.java:466)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>       at oracle.sysman.core.agentpush.ui.deployer.InitializationDeployer.doSSHValidations(InitializationDeployer.java:137)
>       ... 8 more
>   2014-01-15_15-42-17:INFO: Jsch Valdation Failed Problem :Shell Path validation failed Recommendation: Check the property values in the following files in this order, ssPaths_<plat>.properties or sPaths.properties or Paths.properties, in "E:/Oracle/Middleware/oms/oui/prov/resources" directory. If the property values are correct, then ensure the login user account is enabled for remote logins.For more details, refer to the Oracle Enterprise Manager Basic Installation Guide.
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-17:INFO:Updating Action SSHValidationswith Status FAILED and error Message :Shell path is incorrect or not defined.:C:/cygwin/bin/sh.exe(SH_PATH),-c(SH_ARGS) on host mydbhost.mycompany.co.uk and problem Shell Path validation failed and recommendation Check the property values in the following files in this order, ssPaths_<plat>.properties or sPaths.properties or Paths.properties, in "E:/Oracle/Middleware/oms/oui/prov/resources" directory. If the property values are correct, then ensure the login user account is enabled for remote logins.For more details, refer to the Oracle Enterprise Manager Basic Installation Guide.
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-17:INFO:=================action status is not empty FAILED
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-17:INFO:Breaking since the jsch validation  has failed
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-17:INFO:Skipping action CopyAgentImage since some previous step has failed
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-17:INFO:The following action failedSSHValidations
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-17:INFO:TIME TAKEN for Initialization on host mydbhost.mycompany.co.uk is 0: hrs 0: mins 4 sec
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-17:INFO:PERF:HOSTNAME:mydbhost.mycompany.co.uk:InitializationDeployer_EXECUTION_TIME:4018
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-17:INFO:HOST:mydbhost.mycompany.co.uk
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-17:INFO:Destroying Logger
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-17:INFO:======================================Initialization END ====================================
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-17:INFO:Clearing EMSecurityContext EMExecutionContext in BaseDeployerOps

Now I admit I am not an expert on ssh or cygwin or even Oracle12c but the section that reads

> 2014-01-15_15-42-14:INFO:===VALIDATION===:Checking for Nodes Alive
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-14:INFO:RESULT 0
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-14:INFO:====CALLING ACTIONdoNodesAlive
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-14:INFO:action:RemotePasswordCheckperform:true
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-14:INFO:===VALIDATION===:Checking Password Validity on target nodes
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-14:INFO:NODES=mydbhost.mycompany.co.uk Retry Count 5
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-14:INFO:retry count : 1
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-14:INFO:Running cmd C:/cygwin/bin/true.exe on node mydbhost.mycompany.co.uk
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-14:INFO:ssh connect timeout 60000
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-16:INFO:Exit Code : 1
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-16:INFO:Error :
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-16:INFO:Out:
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-16:INFO:Checking for password validity on target nodes : PASSED
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-16:INFO:RESULT 0

suggests that it can contact the remote host (mydbhost.mycompany.co.uk) using the username and password I provided (cyg_server) which suggests the ssh stuff is working.

However the next part

> 2014-01-15_15-42-16:INFO:====CALLING ACTIONdoRemotePasswordCheck
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-16:INFO:action:ShPathCheckperform:true
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-16:INFO:===VALIDATION===:Checking SH_PATH on target nodes
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-16:INFO:isWrongShPath:remotePathPropertiesLoc:E:/Oracle/Middleware/oms/oui/prov/resources Platform id:233
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-16:INFO:NODES=mydbhost.mycompany.co.uk
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-16:INFO:Running cmd C:/cygwin/bin/sh.exe -c C:/cygwin/bin/true.exe on node mydbhost.mycompany.co.uk
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-16:INFO:Action description Execution of command C:/cygwin/bin/sh.exe -c C:/cygwin/bin/true.exe  on host mydbhost.mycompany.co.uk
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-16:INFO:Attempt :1 pty required false  with no inputs
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-17:INFO:C:/cygwin/bin/sh.exe -c C:/cygwin/bin/true.exe execution failed on host mydbhost.mycompany.co.uk
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-17:INFO: OUT null
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-17:INFO: ERR null
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-17:INFO: EXIT CODE1
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-17:INFO: ACTION Execution of command C:/cygwin/bin/sh.exe -c C:/cygwin/bin/true.exe  on host mydbhost.mycompany.co.uk
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-17:INFO:SH_PATH Error Message:C:/cygwin/bin/sh.exe(SH_PATH),-c(SH_ARGS) on host mydbhost.mycompany.co.uk
>
> 2014-01-15_15-42-17:INFO: Jsch Validation Failed Problem :Shell Path validation failed Recommendation: Check the property values in the following files in this order, ssPaths_<plat>.properties or sPaths.properties or Paths.properties, in "E:/Oracle/Middleware/oms/oui/prov/resources" directory. If the property values are correct, then ensure the login user account is enabled for remote logins.For more details, refer to the Oracle Enterprise Manager Basic Installation Guide.

suggests it isn't, because I know that the path (c:\cygwin\bin\sh.exe) is correct and that cyg_server has access to that file (as far as I can tell).

Can anyone point me in the direction I should be going in, because I really have no clue as to what is wrong with this :)

Thanks.

Comment: I have started wondering about something - what use does oem 12c use to "add target"? Is it the currently logged in user (ie \\mydomain\me) or some random oracle user?

Comment: Turns out this was caused by a password error - the instructions I followed to install the CYGWIN server were missing a key step that involved recreating the password for the cyg_server user in /etc/passwd and as a result, it was causing the above error (which doesn't mention passwords at all!)

Answer (score 0):

According to the original poster:

> Turns out this was caused by a password error - the instructions I followed to install the CYGWIN server were missing a key step that involved recreating the password for the cyg_server user in /etc/passwd and as a result, it was causing the above error (which doesn't mention passwords at all!)